# Want to install Ubuntu without any change of my hardisk

Tags: partitioning

During installation I have a screen to specify space. Is that can any change of my harddisk.

Comment: Of course it will change your hard disk. It will split your HDD to partitions. But you should add some more info to your question. Is this a dual-boot with Windows ? (what Windows version), what Ubuntu version ? Do you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows or via wubi.exe ? (inside Windows)

Answer (score 1):

*This is assuming that you already have Windows installed on your machine, and you want to install Ubuntu alongside it, without changing any thing on your hard disk.*

The best way to install Ubuntu without making any changes to your hard disk is using **Wubi**.

#### What is it?

Wubi is a utility that comes in the Ubuntu ISO that you downloaded. It helps install Ubuntu on Windows.

#### What does it do?

Wubi will install Ubuntu on your Windows machine as if Ubuntu were just a normal program. It will not delete anything nor will it change anything in your hard disk; it will only take up some space just like any other program. You'll actually find it in your Add/Remove Programs (or Programs and Features). So, if after you install Ubuntu using Wubi, you want to remove it, just go to Add/Remove Programs and remove it.

#### How to install Ubuntu using Wubi

Wubi is already included in the ISO file that you downloaded from Ubuntu.com. All you have to do is mount the ISO (or insert the CD, or insert the USB) in Windows. You'll get the autoplay box that asks you to "Run Wubi Installer". If the autoplay box does not appear, simply double click the CD icon in your My Computer. If it still doesn't do anything, double click on "wubi.exe" inside the CD/USB. Continue with the installation. I would advice installing Ubuntu on some other partition (like D or E) other than the C partition. Once done, restart your computer, and you'll be presented with an option to go into Windows or Ubuntu. Screenshots can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows), as mentioned by brim4brim.

Comment: wubi is not supported with 13.04.  Go with 12.04 for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Ubuntu without any change on your hard disk, you can use it in live mode. But be warned! It's slower!

Otherway, if you really don't want to partition your hard disk, is better for you to use some other distribution specifically USB, like Puppy
http://puppylinux.org

p.s. really, you can't image to use comfortably Ubuntu without installing it in a partition... but make a partition is less complicate than it should appear, so many howto on the net! ;)
(like that one, very verbose https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition )

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use WUBI to install ubuntu on your Windows partition so that you don't need to partition your hard drive when installing.

Added benefit of using WUBI is you can uninstall Ubuntu from Windows later if you decide you don't want to use it anymore as if it was any other program :)

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Have fun :)